Vinyl Plank Subfloor Variance
Any experience with variance in subfloor thickness? I failed to realize that 1/4” SurePly is 0.205” whiles 1/4 sanded plywood is 0.234”. Wondering if the difference will cause issues long term. Most other posts mention 1/16 being about the tolerance for transition points (between doorways) and this is less than 1/32. Since I’m not using a transition strip, the flooring will be continuous into the next room. One room has the 1/4” SurePly and the other has 1/4” sanded plywood.

Products with a solid core and minimum thickness of 5.5mm will tolerate that without any issue.
If you care to mitigate even more you can put down some [floor level and patch] to ramp the difference.
I have laid LVP over thickness differences far greater than that. I ramp with the leveling compound and have no issues.
